# How to change TextBlock Text Binding in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, binding, textblock

I'm working in huge application and I have one small problem
My Application has two languages (Arabic / English).
I have ComboBox And I would like to change the display content according to the language.

This is my ComboBox XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCustomerGroup" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
    Margin="2" SelectedValuePath="CustomerGroupId"  Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CustomerGroupId, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
    <!--<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>-->
</ComboBox>
```

This is my method:

```
private void FillCustomerGroups()
{
    var oClsCustomers = new ClsCustomerGroups();
    var lstCustGrps = oClsCustomers.GetData();
    cmbCustomerGroup.ItemsSource = lstCustGrps.ToList<TbCustomerGroups>();
    cmbCustomerGroup.DisplayMemberPath = Helper.CurrLang == Helper.SystemLanguage.Arabic ? "CustomerGroupAName" : "CustomerGroupEName";
    cmbCustomerGroup.SelectedValuePath = "CustomerGroupId";
}
```

I got this result:

[image: result]

This is my database:

[image: database]

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when `DisplayMemberPath` is set wrong, or bindable property is not a string and has no overriden `ToString()` method.

Try add new property to your `TbCustomerGroups`, for example `CurrentGroupName` like this

```
 public string CurrentGroupName => Helper.CurrLang == Helper.SystemLanguage.Arabic ? CustomerGroupAName : CustomerGroupEName;
```

Then set `cmbCustomerGroup.DisplayMemberPath = "CurrentGroupName"`

Also check that `CustomerGroupAName` and `CustomerGroupEName` are strings or have `ToString()` method

**UPDATE**

Also don't use `<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>` if you use `DisplayMemberPath`

Comment: I tried it, It is not working.. I'm sure that CustomerGroupAName and CustomerGroupEName are strings.